# Does Weblogic/Glassfish guarantees the order of application deployment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, weblogic, java-ee-6, java-ee-5

Java EE 5 does not guarantee any application deployment ordering.
This feature was introduced in Java EE 6.
We use Oracle WebLogic 10.3.2 and it is Java EE 5 compliant.
We also use GlassFish 3.

We have an ear with several war files.
As I can see both WebLogic and GlassFish start the applications in the order in which they are specified in `application.xml`.

Is this the way how WebLogic/GlassFish deploy applications from an ear?
Or could the order be different from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's implemented internally, at least from my experience WebLogic always start modules inside an ear as the order they're specified in application.xml.

In our project there is dependency between some modules so we adjust their order in application.xml to make sure the one being depended is loaded at first.